# How to set the form's default button in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, swift

In a OS X app, if I have a form with a couple of buttons, how do I nominate a *default* button for the form? By *default* button I mean the button that acts when I hit *Enter*.

I've been trying to learn Swift, and so I've been experimenting building little OS X apps using Xcode 6.

All my programming experience is in Windows desktop applications, so I might be looking at this all wrong, and maybe using the wrong terminology here.

Comment: Did you find https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Articles/MakingaButtontheDefaultButton.html and try a literal Swift translation of that?

Comment: @Tommy I tried searching in Apple's documentation but couldn't find the answer. That's why I thought I was not using the correct terminology. Not even searching by the title of your link gives me your link as one of the answers. I need to learn how to use that documentation.

Comment: I wouldn't bother; Apple's existing documentation HTML has serious issues — e.g. pinch to zoom isn't usable even on Apple devices — so the whole lot is getting an overhaul with the iOS 8 launch. Don't waste time getting used to it now!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set they button's key equivalent to `\r`. This is most easily done in Interface Builder by selecting "Key Equivalent" and pressing Enter.

[image]